# Listen to Exchange server and catch every new mail message

Tags: python, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-transport-agents

I need my exchange server to catch every new mail it recieves and run some custom code on it. I've read about Transport Agents, EWS and ADO but couldn't find a clear, working example.

Answer (score 0):

Given the amount of detail in your question a Transport Agent would be the best option Here are a few examples

https://github.com/Pro/exchange-catchall

http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2013/01/21/how-to-write-an-exchange-2013-transport-agent.aspx

If an example its clear what isn't clear about it ? if something doesn't work what doesn't work.

Cheers
Glen